How to connect to a private Cosmos for MongoDB datasource with Azure AI Search?
My end goal is to be able to automate this creation through terraform, however, first I need to be able to do this through the portal to understand what is happening.
I've created an Azure AI Search resource and I'm trying to connect to a Cosmos MongoDB database. Both resources have their own private endpoints which are under the same subscription, resource group, location, virtual network, and subnet. The CosmosDB is public access disabled, and private access goes through that endpoint. The Azure Search allows select IP addresses.
When in the portal for Azure AI Search, I go to "Datasources", add a new datasource, and select the "Choose an existing connection" option, because my CosmosDB is already made. However, when choosing this connection, I get this error:
BadRequest: Response status code does not indicate success: Forbidden (403); Substatus: 0; ActivityId:...; 
Reason: (Request originated from IP ... through public internet. 
This is blocked by your Cosmos DB account firewall settings...

How am I able to connect to my CosmosDB account if it is private and has a private endpoint?

To connect an Azure Cognitive Search resource to a private Cosmos DB database using a private endpoint, you’ll need to ensure that both services can communicate through the Azure Virtual Network. Here is a step-by-step guide to set this up:

The Azure AI Search indexers for MongoDB and Gremlin are in preview and not intended for production use. Request access to preview APIs. The SQL API indexer is generally available and can be used in production.

Create a Private Endpoint for Cosmos DB

Navigate to your Cosmos DB account in the Azure portal.
Under the “Networking” section, click “Private endpoints.”
Click “+ Private endpoint” and follow the wizard to create a private endpoint for Cosmos DB. Ensure it is associated with the same virtual network and subnet as the Azure Cognitive Search.



In Azure AI Search, add private access to other resources using Private Links. Click “Add shared private link” to request a private endpoint to access protected resources.
In Azure AI Search:

Go to your Azure AI Search resource.

Navigate to Networking.

Ensure that Azure AI Search is set up to use private endpoints:

Under Private endpoints, create a new private endpoint if one doesn’t exist.
Follow the same process as above to configure the private endpoint in the VNet and subnet.


Your request must be approved by the resource owner before you can connect and configure the indexer to run in the private environment.



{
    "name": "indexer",
    "dataSourceName": "datasource",
    "targetIndexName": "index",
    "parameters": {
        "configuration": {
            "executionEnvironment": "private"
        }
    },
    "fieldMappings": []
}


For private endpoints to work correctly, you need to ensure DNS resolution is correctly configured:
Private DNS Zones:

Go to “Private DNS zones” in the Azure portal.

Create a private DNS zone for each service (e.g., privatelink.documents.azure.com for Cosmos DB and privatelink.search.windows.net for Azure Cognitive Search).

Link these DNS zones to your virtual network.
DNS Resolution:

Ensure your virtual network is configured to use these private DNS zones for name resolution.
Update Cosmos DB Firewall:

Navigate to your Cosmos DB account.

Under the “Firewall and virtual networks” section, add the virtual network and subnet where Azure Cognitive Search is deployed. This will allow traffic from the Azure Cognitive Search private endpoint.


Update Azure Cognitive Search IP Restrictions:

Navigate to your Azure Cognitive Search resource.

Under the “Networking” section, review the IP firewall rules to ensure that access is allowed from the Cosmos DB private endpoint.
Add a New Data Source:

Navigate to your Azure Cognitive Search resource.

Go to the “Data sources” section and click “+ Add”.

Select “Cosmos DB” as the data source type.

Choose “Choose an existing connection” and select your Cosmos DB private endpoint connection.

Set Data Source Credentials:

Ensure you use the correct connection string and credentials for Cosmos DB. If you encounter issues, verify that the private endpoint DNS resolution and network configurations are correct.


Refer to the following MSDOCs for more details:

Create Or Update Private Endpoint Connections with REST API in Azure Cosmos DB
Creact and access a private search service
Connect through a shared private link in Azure AI Search


I am unable to create a shared private link to my Cosmos MongoDB resource. The Provisioning State resolves to "Failed" and I believe this is because the "Target sub-resource" field only has an option for Sql and not for MongoDB. Does that mean that private shared links are not an option for a MongoDB instance of CosmosDB?
